# Photoshop file layers not visible after saving

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I created a PSD file with several layers and group layers. Last night when I went to open it there was only one layer and the layer looked a distorted TV Screen.

When I clicked on the file in the preview I can see the last layer that I had opened, but when I open it it's just black.  The size of my file  238MB showing that it is a large file and the layers should be there.

I've renamed the file and duplicated it, even took it to work and opened it on another machine but still the same problem. So I duplicated the image and unlocked the layers and saved it. My 238MB file dropped down to a 1.2MB file after I saved it and all of my layer and groups are gone.

I'm not sure why this is happening with my file, has anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: it looks like your file might be corrupted, in which case we can't help you. Check [ask] on what kind of questions are accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

Absent screenshots and other contextual information I am basically guessing, but I *think* you've created a Smart Object and are entering that instead of staying in your main file...